# How to pass both Notmapped And ViewBag value to view from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace OvhokEMarket.Models.OnlyModels.Account.Security
{
public class IdentityUserExtraEntity : IdentityUser
{
  [NotMapped]
  public string EncryptedId { get; set; }
}
}
  

      [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListRoles()
        {
        
        ViewBag.SubscribeRemainingDays = CheckPlanOfClient_RemainingDays();//To Display remainging days in view.    
        ListRolesViewModels listRolesViewModels = new ListRolesViewModels();
        listRolesViewModels.IdentityRoleExtraEntityLIST = roleManager.Roles;
        foreach (var RolesName in listRolesViewModels.IdentityRoleExtraEntityLIST)
        {
           RolesName.EncryptedId = protector.Protect(RolesName.Id.ToString());//Encrypted data to pass in Notmapped attribute
                 
        }
             
          return View(listRolesViewModels);
        }
        }
```

I am trying to pass both Notmapped attribute and ViewBag value. But it seems that ViewBag override Notmapped value as null while passing to view.

How do pass both value to view?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in the ListRoles() method and check the ViewBag value, I assume you are querying the data from the database, if that is the case, the Notmapped property's value should be null. Because, the `NotMapped` attribute is used to specify that an entity or property is not to be mapped to a table or column in the database. So, for the properties which using this attribute, if we query database, the value will be null. To get the values, you could remove the `NotMapped` attribute or reset the value after querying the database.

Comment: If i remove that notmapped attribute new column will be created, i am using that temporary variable to pass encrypted id in route as url data.

Answer (score 0):

I think use this way.

You should have a view and its name should be "ListRoles". Then,

in ListRoles.cshtml

```
@model ListRolesViewModels

@{
   var subscribeRemainingDays = (write whatever type it is)ViewBag.SubscribeRemainingDays;
}

@foreach (var RolesName in Model.IdentityRoleExtraEntityLIST)
{
   var rolesName = RolesName.EncryptedId;
}
```

Comment: This not the solution. Thanks for the support. I am trying to pass both value. Viewbag and the notmapped value from controller to view. And i am not able to achieve. Some how viewbag override the notmapped value as null. Still cannot find solutions.